# How to handle onBackPressed at parent fragment

Tags: java, android

I don't know how to handle the `onBackPressed()` at the parent fragment.

For example, I have:

```
[1] -> [2]
```

- `[1]`: The parent fragment
- `[2]`: The activity which i used the method
  startActivity(intent) in `[1]`

So in `[2]` I call the method `onBackPressed()`. So it will return to the `[1]`

The problem is: I dont know how to catch that event in `[1]`
Note: I know that instead of `startActivity` I can use `startActivityForResult` and then catch the `onActivityResult` in `[1]`. I just want to know if there is any possible way I can catch the `onBackPressed` event.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `startActivityForResult` you can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

In **activity 2**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Your_preferd_name", 0);
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("key",data);
editor.commit();
}
```

In **activity 1 or Parent Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("Your_prefered_name", 0);
String data = sp.getString("key", "default_value");
}
```

Also, you can maintain a static class, In which you can update its data variable in **Activity 2** `onBackPressed()` and retrieve it from **Activity 1** `onResume` or whenever you want.